# Ruby on Rails about the Structure App Sample

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

im learning about Ruby on Rails but i have somes questions and not find the answers i hope help me in this , and thanks.

1 - If i construct a e-commerce store  , im have create a controller for each aspect
Example:
1 controller to Admin
1 Controller to Products
1 Controller to Store
1 Controller to Client

My question is , are correct ? One controller for each ?

2 - Im analise the scaffold code , im not want use this , want write my app but  i analyse the code and see the diferent routs , example , Create is Post , how i define this actions , the scaffold use 
New
Show
Create..and more some
This classes(Actions) is default ?or  the code in the controller of generated scaffold make this how i define if this is get or post ?

I hope you can answer these questions, thank you for support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1 - If i construct a e-commerce store , im have create a controller
>   for each aspect Example: 1 controller to Admin 1 Controller to
>   Products 1 Controller to Store 1 Controller to Client
>
> My question is , are correct ? One controller for each ?

Yes, one controller for each!

And don't forget: Skinny Controller, Fat Model!

Comment: thanks , help me many.the second question someone can response for me?